# YII2 SQL: Get count of column with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

I want to get the sum of `li_units_bought` for rows based on `li_order_id`.

I am joining multiple tables for it. Here is my query:

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('oid, ord_tracking_no as `Tracking No`, site_name as Region,adv_name as Advertiser, line_id as LineId, li_name as LineName
            , li_status as StatusCode, prd_desc as Product, li_version as Version, date_format(lrh_updated_date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") as `Submit Date`
            , date_format(li_start_date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") as `Start Date`
            , date_format(li_end_date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") as `End Date`, li_is_rush as isRushOrder
            , li_type as Type, ord_assigned_user as `Assigned User`, status_desc as Status

            , SUM(`li_units_bought`) as Goal
            , ldp_total_delivery as `Delivered`
            , if(li_type="STANDARD",((ldp_pacing*180)/100)+1,((ldp_pacing+1)*1*180)) as Pacing
            , li_cost_type as `Cost Type`
            , ord_total_budget as `Total Budget`
            , li_is_automated
            ,li_target_server as Adserver
            ,li_del_pac_indicator as `DFP Report`
            ,li_submit_by
            ' )
            ->from('lineitems')
            ->innerJoin('orders','oid = li_order_id')
            ->leftJoin('advertisers','adv_id=ord_adv_id')
            ->leftJoin('sites','site_id=ord_site_id')
            ->leftJoin('products','prd_id=li_product')
            ->leftJoin('status_ref','status_id=li_status')
            ->leftJoin('users',"user_id='".$userid."'")
            ->leftJoin('user_role_profiles','urp_id=user_primary_role')
            ->leftJoin('lineitem_delivery_pacing','ldp_line_id = line_id')
            ->innerJoin("user_site_assoc","usc_site_id=ord_site_id and usc_userid='".$_SESSION['userId']."'")
            ->innerJoin("lineitem_revision_history", "lrh_lineitemid = line_id")
            ->where(" li_status not in ('Z','X') $cond")
            ->andWhere("li_order_id = oid")

            ->groupBy('line_id');
```

I am getting only the `li_units_bought` for one row. Not the sum of the rows having the same `li_order_id`.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how you accessing to the result ? show the related code

Comment: @scaisEdge im running the raw query in my database which i get by using `createCommand()`

Comment: ok and how you accessing to the result values .. you use a widget  .. ?  or echo the result? ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I'm returning the result as a response to an ajax call

Comment: You need to group by `li_order_id` instead of `line_id`.

Comment: @rob006 the thing is if I group by `li_order_id` I donot get the other details which I want based on each `line_id`

Comment: Then I suggest to use another query for that. If you group by `line_id` `sum()` will return sum for rows with the same `line_id`. You can't do much about this without writing twisted subqueries, which probably will be slower and less readable.

Comment: @rob006 yeah you're right. I'll have to resort to that. Thanks for your time though. Thank you.